# Sybase: How to get the current date in mm/dd/yyyy format?

Tags: sql, datetime, sybase

I want to insert the mm/dd/yyyy format into a table and after that compare it with the current date when fetching results from the table to display.

The getdate() function returns the complete timestamp and am unable to extract the date in my desired format.

Comment: Have you tried [`datepart()`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01621.0510/doc/html/emc1297434461737.html)?

Comment: But datepart() gives only a part of the date right - like day,month,year or day of week. How can I get a format like above?

Comment: You're right. I mistakenly thought that it allows for custom patterns.

Comment: What is the `data type` of this column?

Comment: I have selected DATETIME for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for this SQL to make the conversion:

```
select convert(varchar, date_column, 101) from the_table
```

The important part in part in this case is `101` which is specification of `mm/dd/yyyy` format as per documentation. If you have Sybase ASE 15.7 use [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X41864.htm), if you have SAP ASE 16.0 (released 2014) use [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1600/doc/html/san1393050437990.html) (has more options).

Comment: No @Rahul am looking for something like this

UPDATE #sse_template_audit
SET cre_date = getdate()
WHERE cre_date= NULL

I want to enter the date to that column in mm/dd/yyyy format only.

Comment: @Swat:- Did you tried this:- UPDATE #sse_template_audit SET cre_date = convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) WHERE cre_date= NULL Although not very sure if that works!!

Comment: Can you tell me why is that 101 used for? Am a bit confused about that.

Comment: 101 is for mm/dd/yyyy format. Check this out:- http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm